# resetear un jcombobox al finalizar de completar el formulario

Tags: java, formularios, combobox

Estoy llenando un formulario.

Para evitar el error del usuario en uno de los `campos` a llenar lo limito a un `combobox`, y cuando finaliza el llenado y da enviar, puedo borrar todo , pero el `combobox` me queda en el valor que deja el usuario.

Los valores los tengo en el código del programa , a lo que voy es que selecciono uno de los valores que tiene (en este caso son ciudades) para llenar el formulario, al finalizar envío esos datos a mi base, y limpio el formulario, pero en el `JCombobox` se mantiene seleccionado el mismo valor y no vuelve a la selección en blanco, ejemplo selecciono "NUEVA YORK", limpio el formulario y queda en esa selección, no volviendo a "SELECCIONE CIUDAD". Me explico ahora?? Intentos no he hecho porque no se como hacerlo, por ende no metí mano porque no se por donde empezar. Gracias

Intentaré explicarlo nuevamente.
Los `valores seleccionables` los tengo cargados por el `código` del `sw`, **no** vienen de la `base de datos`.
Como agregué en la edición, mi usuario llena el formulario, cuando llega al `combobox` éste dice **"Seleccione ciudad"**, el usuario lo cambia por el que necesite. Finaliza de llenar el `formulario`, `click` en `ENVIAR` y se guardan los datos en la `base de datos` y aprovecho el evento del botón para **borrar** los campos del formulario, pero el `combobox` no vuelve al **"Seleccione ciudad"**. Eso quiero hacer. Ahora si me expliqué claramente?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: Ese combobox lo llenas de forma manual  o lo extraes de alguna Base de Datos ? si lo haces de forma manual, puedes volver a agregar los campos con el .addItem o si es desde una BD usas RemoveAllItems y vuelves a cargar los datos

Comment: No se si no me explico bien, o no entienden. los valores seleccionables los tengo cargados por el código del sw, no vienen de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bueno conocer tu código, pero por lo que comentas podría valerte con introducir esta linera de código en la función que utilices para resetear tu formulario.

```
jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(0);
```